# EXCEL - set sell value from another cell

Tags: excel, cell

I am looking for a way to edit a cell by another one. Is there any method out there to write e.g. "Test" in cell B1 by writting it in cell A1. B1 should stay empty before the values is entered, so no =A1. I need something like "SetValue(B1, "Test")". No other programms are allowed, only Excel. I really would appreciate any help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way of doing it,

In `B1`,

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)`

Checks if `A1` is blank. If its blank, makes the cell `B1` also blank. If not copies `A1` to `B1`.

Comment: Thank you, it gave me some ideas to solve my specific problem :)

Comment: @Kadepp Thanks!! please upvote if you found this useful

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
=if(A1="","",A1)
```

B1 cell will still appear empty while nothing is entered in A1